# Build Android application at PhoneGap Build

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, ios, cordova

I'm building a web application using PhoneGap Build with debug mode disabled but when I download the file is in debug mode. This only happens on Android, all the other OS's are correct.

How can I disable debug mode on Android applications?

Answer (score 3):

When you run the build.  Use:

```
cordova build android --release
```

or

```
phonegap build android --release
```

If upload to play store errors ==>

Upload failed
You uploaded a debuggable APK. For security reasons you need to disable debugging before it can be published in Google Play

Make sure your manifest is set thus: android:debuggable="false"
e.g.

```
<application android:debuggable="false" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Answer (score 1):

In your android project, open res/xml and cordova.xml or phonegap.xml, and change the debuger level in phonegap.

Presently it is `<log level="DEBUG"/>`.

You can change it to:

1. ASSERT
2. ERROR
3. INFO
4. VERBOSE
5. WARN

Use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html